# deleting files with perl

Tags: perl, delete-file

I'm trying to write a perl script that reads filenames in a test.txt file into an array, and then deletes the files based on the filenames in the array.  Here's what I've got so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE, "test.txt") or die("Unable to open file.");

my @data = <FILE>;

close(FILE);

foreach my $line (@data){
        unlink($line);
}
```

test.txt and remove_files.pl are in the same directory as the files to be removed.  I can't figure out why the script won't delete the files.  Am I missing a module?

Comment: The first hint would be to check the error: `unlink($line) or warn "$0: could not unlink $line: $!\n"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lines read from a file with the readline operator (`<...>`) will include the newline character. You'll need to remove it, or else you will be trying to delete a file called `"myfile.txt\n"` instead of `"myfile.txt"`. Use Perl's [`chomp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#chomp) function to trim your input:

```
foreach $line (@data){
    chomp($line);
    unlink($line);
}
```

Comment: You can also do `chomp @data; unlink @data;`, as both commands take lists as arguments. I.e. no need for a loop.

Comment: @ikegami It will be as easy as before to check for errors, but in case of an error, you wont be able to tell which file couldn't be deleted.