# Executing shell command containing quotations in Perl

Tags: shell, perl

I have method that is listing files/folders to be deleted on unix. Then I delete it with the code:

```
for my $line (@linesFiles) {
    my $command = "rm '$line';"; # or my $command = "rmdir '$line';";
    my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
        system ($command);
        };      
    }
```

Mots of the time it works, but sometimes files/folders have incorrect names containing quotation marks, like `some\folder\incorrect'name` or `some\folder\incorrect"name`. I would need to delete those files/folder as well.

But using my code I'm getting EOF error or that file/folder does not exist error.
When using `q` or `qq`, the quotation marks were removed from the filename resulting in file/folder does not exist error.

Would anybody help me with how to modify the code, so it would be able to delete files/folders containing any potentially dangerous (at least for this case) characters like `" ' $ { }`  ?

Comment: Any reason to not use `unlink`? (see [deleting files with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9265523/4990392))

Comment: I need to delete folders as well, and if delete fails, I need to know for which file/folder it failed

Comment: All the more reasons to use `unlink`, as you get precise feedback on error. Also see [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path)'s `remove_tree`.

Comment: @JanFi86 *if delete fails, I need to know for which file/folder* I was going to say that that would be a reason to NOT use a shell command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build a shell command, you can use [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) (or [Win32::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote)).

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $shell_cmd = shell_quote( "rm", "--", $qfn );
system( $shell_cmd );
die( "Couldn't launch shell to unlink \"$qfn\": $!\n" )                             if $? == -1;
die( "Shell killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )." while trying to unlink \"$qfn\"\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "Shell exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )." while trying to unlink \"$qfn\"\n" )  if $? >> 8;
```

---

But why involve a shell at all? You can use the multi-argument form of `system`.

```perl
system( "rm", "--", $qfn );
die( "Couldn't launch rm to unlink \"$qfn\": $!\n" )                             if $? == -1;
die( "rm killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )." while trying to unlink \"$qfn\"\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die( "rm exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )." while trying to unlink \"$qfn\"\n" )  if $? >> 8;
```

---

But why involve an external tool at all. You can use [`unlink`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink) to delete files.

```perl
unlink( $qfn )
   or die( "Can't unlink \"$qfn\": $!\n" );
```